# Python sum function returning rounded result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python `3.8.5` to sum a list of floats as follows:

```
>> prices = [12.3, 11.99, 1.99, 5]
>> sum(prices)
31.279999999999998
```

here as you see, the sum function is returning a rounded result where the real sum is equal to `31.28`. What sum has a same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `float`s implementation, not `sum`. You might use `decimal.Decimal` to avoid that problem.

```
import decimal
prices = [decimal.Decimal("12.3"), decimal.Decimal("11.99"), decimal.Decimal("1.99"), decimal.Decimal("5")]
print(sum(prices))
```

Output:

```
31.28
```